# storing image as blob in database

Tags: c#, database

I'm trying to store an image as a BLOB in my database, like this:

```
    c = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO korisnici VALUES( '" + entity.Id + "','" + entity.Prezime + "','" + entity.Ime + "','" + **SlikaUBase64(entity.Slika, ImageFormat.Bmp)**...
```

This is my function which creates a BLOB from an image:

```
    public string SlikaUBase64(Image image, ImageFormat format)
{
    //slika u byte[]
    byte[] prazan=new byte[0];
    if (image == null) return Convert.ToBase64String(prazan);
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    image.Save(ms, format);
    byte[] imageBytes = ms.ToArray();

    // byte[] u base64
    string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
    return base64;
}
```

and I'm getting this exception: There was an error while trying to serialize parameter http://tempuri.org/:entity. The InnerException message was 'Type 'System.Drawing.Bitmap' with data contract name
'Bitmap:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Drawing' is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver or add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.'. Please see InnerException for more details.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Holy sql injection vulnerability, Batman!

Comment: Also, tempuri.org is the fake company Microsoft used in all of their serialization example code. They've since allowed the domain to expire. It sounds like you've only partially adapted a sample from somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I would not pass in the Image reference but rather the Byte[].